# display div on scroll

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a similar one page scroll effect similar to this http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html but without having to use a plugin.

My code is to check for available divs (sections) and increment by 1 on scroll and then either fade it in, redirect to it (window.location = #s1) or animate a scroll to it. Problem is the scrolling is sensitive and continuos, one scroll of the mouse and goes from 1 to 5 with this example. When animating a scroll to the div, it also triggers the event listener.

Is it possible to pause the scroll event listener after the first scroll, display the div and then un pause the listener?

```
<div id="sections">
    <div id="s1">section 1</div>    
    <div id="s2">section 2</div>    
    <div id="s3">section 3</div>    
    <div id="s4">section 4</div>    
    <div id="s5">section 5</div>
</div>

#sections div {
    min-height: 1000px;
}

var tempScrollTop= 0; 
var currentSection = 0;
var maxSections = $("#sections div").size() - 1;

$(window).scroll(function() { 
    currentScrollTop = $("body").scrollTop(); 

    if (tempScrollTop > currentScrollTop ) {
    // scroll up
    } else if (tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop) {
    // scroll down

        if (currentSection <= maxSections) { 
            currentSection++;
        }

        $('#sections div').hide();
        $("#s"+currentSection).fadeIn('slow');
    }

    tempScrollTop = currentScrollTop; 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0qqdq9ab/2/

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have the HTML in place with divs as `myDiv0`, `myDiv1`..., you can capture the arrow keys event and scroll to the `div` as

```
var currCount = 0;
var totalDivs = $('div[id^="myDiv"]').length;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
switch(e.which) {
    case 37: // left
    break;

    case 38: // up
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv" + (--currCount)%totalDivs).offset().top
    }, 1000);
    break;

    case 39: // right
    break;

    case 40: // down
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv" + (++currCount)%totalDivs).offset().top
    }, 1000);
    break;

    default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
}
e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
```

});

Comment: I'd like to be able to scroll rather than using the arrow keys

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting `html` to begin `id` of element to end with `0` , defining `scroll` event handler as named function , substituting `.one()` for `.on() , using`setTimeout()`to create minimal delay before re-attaching`scroll` event listener

```js
var tempScrollTop = 0;
var currentScrollTop = 0;
var currentSection = 0;
var maxSections = $("#sections div").length;

function scroller() {

  var fx = function(setSection) {

    currentSection = !!setSection 
                     ? --currentSection % maxSections 
                     : ++currentSection % maxSections;
    
    if (currentSection > -1) {
      $("#sections div").hide()
        .filter("#s" + currentSection)
        .fadeIn("slow", function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            tempScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
            $(this).one("scroll", scroller)
          })
        });
      // if scroll up to first `#s0`
    } else {
      currentSection = 0;
      tempScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
      $(this).one("scroll", scroller)
    }
  }
  currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (currentScrollTop > tempScrollTop && currentSection < maxSections - 1) {

    fx.call(this)
  } else {
    if (currentSection < maxSections && currentScrollTop < tempScrollTop) {
      fx.call(this, true)
    } else {
      $(this).on("scroll.temp", function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < tempScrollTop) {
          $(this).off("scroll.temp");
          currentScrollTop = tempScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
          fx.call(this, true)
        }
      })
    }
  }
}

$(window).one("scroll", scroller);
```

```css
#sections div {
  min-height: 1000px;
}
#s0 {
  background: gold;
}
#s1 {
  background: green;
}
#s2 {
  background: brown;
}
#s3 {
  background: blue;
}
#s4 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sections">
  <div id="s0">section 0</div>
  <div id="s1">section 1</div>
  <div id="s2">section 2</div>
  <div id="s3">section 3</div>
  <div id="s4">section 4</div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0qqdq9ab/5/